# Как называется группа ведьм?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, словосочетания

К летающим животным вроде птиц и летучих мышей мы применяем слово "стая", к насекомым — "рой". Самолёты и прочие воздушные транспортные средства считают, полагаю, группами.
А как однозначно можно назвать несколько ведьм, летящих в ступах, верхом на мётлах или иным магическим образом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Птицы могут летать не только стаями, но и табунами, и [**косяками**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/1967/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BA).
*Заметив **табун пасущихся дроф**, сообразуясь с направлением ветра и более вероятным направлением, в котором полетят стронутые дрофы, охотники намечают план охоты* (В. В. Рябов. Книга об охоте).

Насекомые летают не только роями, но и стаями, и полчищами.
*Обычно **стая саранчи** летит со скоростью 10-15 км/ч на высоте до 600 м* (из энциклопедии).
*На Волгоградскую область надвигаются **полчища саранчи.***
У Даля: [**облако саранчи**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=2KtiRSUTRMEC&pg=PA1107&lpg=PA1107&dq=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=VnXetO8U59&sig=ACfU3U2PAmp8ksXflX5W_WKstY2HG86lEg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPnua068foAhUs_SoKHXgTAkI4ChDoATAJegQICxBK#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8&f=false).

Как однозначно назвать летящую **группу колдуний**, мнение о существовании которых не является однозначным? Выбирайте.

*Кровать завизжала, как **стая ведьм**, пролетающих по ночному небу в предрассветный час* (Рэй Брэдбери. Примирительница).

*Средневековые жители уверяли, что целые **сонмы ведьм**, вампиров и разного вида оборотней орудовали в лесах и горных местностях Трансильвании...* (В. Брюс. В поисках вампиров)

*Вой стоял такой, будто **сонмище ведьм** летело на шабаш* (С. Спилберг. Мартовский выползень).

*Утопая в дремучих лесах и журча глубокими ручьями, ощетиниваясь неприветливыми горами и башнями неприступных замков, звеня колоколами соборов и молоточками мастеров, Мерден рождал сонмы священников и **полчища ведьм**...* (А. Торн. Черный призрак)

P. S. Вот еще картинка.
*Поезд ехал по высокой насыпи — внизу темнел густой лес, над лесом висела полная белая луна; на фоне луны высвечивался далёкий **косяк ведьм на мётлах**, спешащих куда-то по своим ведьминским делам — все в чёрном, с высокими остроконечными шляпами. Ведьмы как ведьмы...* (М. Бабкин. Слимперия)

Answer (score 1):

> А как однозначно можно назвать несколько ведьм, летящих в ступах,
>   верхом на мётлах или иным магическим образом?

Эскадрилья.

Если серьезно, ведьмы существа одушевленные и наделенные разумом. Для таких ситуаций в русском языке специального слова не предусмотрено. Все эти косяки и табуны подходят лишь частично, они не очень точно соответствуют ситуации, разве что переносно. Табун он, извините, тогда табун, когда предоставлен самому себе. А если под седлом - так он и не табун вовсе.

Так что или группа или отряд. последнее, впрочем тоже весьма условно соответвует ситуации.

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь в виду.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взляд, чтобы определиться, нужно принять во внимание различие между обозначением *множества* (стая, стайка, сонм, скопление, полчище, тьма, туча и пр.) и *формой* его *организации* (косяк, клин). Кроме того, одни обозначения множества указывают на *общность* (стая), другие - лишь на *количество* неважно чего (сонм, сонмище, полчища). Для такой разновидности летучей ведьмы как **валькирия**, весьма употребительно "**стая**" (можно легко найти в книгах, театральной критике и изложениях либретто: http://wagner.su/book/export/html/137).

Для ведьм в ступах или на помеле верхом можно применить то же понятие - **стая (стайка) ведьм** и лишь в случаях гипер-иронии можно говорить о "*косяках*", "*клинах*" или ином строевом порядке *стаи ведьм, валькирий*.

Comment: А в чём особенность валькирий, на Ваш взгляд? Если они путешествуют на крылатых конях, то группа таких существ должна именоваться чем-то вроде взвода.